# Rolling back app update

Tags: updates, crashes

A recent app update (adding annoying adds) has been caused some stability issues, app crashes, etc. How can I roll back a Google Play store app to a previous stable version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the official site of the respective app for previous versions if available.

If you have a backup of the previous version, uninstall the current version and install the old version.

Try to avoid Update all option and make sure to turn off automatic updates in the Google play store.